# How to detect image brightness and sharpness in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I tried applying **tesseract ocr** on image but before applying OCR I want to **improve the quality of the image** so that OCR efficiency increase,

1. How to **detect image brightness** and increase or decrease the brightness of the image as per requirement.
2. How to **detect image sharpness**

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy way to do that, if your images are similar to each other you can define "correct" brightness and adjust it on unprocessed images.

But what is "correct" brightness? You can use histogram to match this. See figure bellow. If you establish your correct histogram you can calibrate other images to it.

[image: Richard Szeliski, Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications]

*Richard Szeliski, Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications*

I think you can use the autofocus method. You must check contrast histogram of image and define what is sharp to you.

[image: https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-autofocus.htm]

[source](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-autofocus.htm)

Answer (score 0):

*Basic recommendation, using the gray images is better on OCR

You can use the BRISQUE image quality assessment for scoring the image quality, it's available as a library. check it out, a smaller score means good quality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try it.